# Magento $h1Tags regex for all tags

Tags: php, regex, magento-1.9

This code only replace to h1 tag product name I would like to replace in all tags

```
public function replaceName($observer)
{
    $accessToPage = array(
        'catalog_product_view',
        'review_product_list',
    );

    if(!in_array(Mage::helper('mage_seoall/request')->getCurrentFullActionName(), $accessToPage)){
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if($block->getNameInLayout() != 'product.info'){
            return;
        }

        $productSeoName = Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductSeoName();
        if(!$productSeoName){
            return;
        }

        $transport    = $observer->getTransport();
        $normalOutput = $observer->getTransport()->getHtml();
        $modifyOutput = $normalOutput;
        $h1Tags = array();
        preg_match_all('#<h1[^>]*>(.*)?</h1>#is', $normalOutput, $h1Tags);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($h1Tags[1]); $i++) {
            $modifyOutput  = str_replace($h1Tags[1][$i], $productSeoName, $modifyOutput);
        }

        $transport->setHtml($modifyOutput);
    }
}
```

This magento extension changing product name which is only in h1 tag but on my template h1 tags is only product page so product name is seeing different on other page such as listing checkout, cart ajax cart...

I am try to change regex for all tags but I couldnt......

Comment: Used this line preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content);

Comment: Itried before it doesnt work.... I think need to define all tag in whole codes preg_match_all('#<h1[^>]*>(.*)?</h1>#is', $normalOutput, $h1Tags);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($h1Tags[1]); $i++) {
            $modifyOutput  = str_replace($h1Tags[1][$i], $productSeoName, $modifyOutput);
        }